# Modify the default Filter Field in a Telerik MVC ComboBox

Tags: telerik-mvc

When filtering a Telerik MVC ComboBox the control defaults to filtering from the values in the DataTextField.  My ComboBox is bound to Data that has multiple fields that I'm using to display in a table with custom templates.  I'm aware that there's no out of the box solution for filtering on multiple fields, but I'm wondering if there's a way to run the filter on a field where I've combined the multiple values.

Here's my comboBox:

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(m => m.InputData.PublicationId)
    .DataTextField("ID")
    .DataValueField("ID")
    .BindTo(Model.Publications)
    .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
    .TemplateId("pubListItemTemplate")
    .HeaderTemplateId("pubListHeaderTemplate")
)
```

My data is structured as follows:

```
{ ID: "AJ", Description: "American Journal", Combined: "AJ American Journal" }, etc...]
```

The issue here is that if the user types in "AJ" the filter will find the example above, but if they type in "American" it will not; because the specified DataTextField is filtering on the ID.

I need for it to filter on the field called "Combined", but I still need to use the "ID" as the DataTextField so that the ID is only what is displayed in the combo after they've selected the item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was provided to me on the Telerik forum, and I have confirmed that it solves my problem:

```
@(Html.Kendo().ComboBoxFor(m => m.InputData.PublicationId)
    .DataTextField("ID")
    .DataValueField("ID")
    .Events(events => events.Filter("onPubFilter"))
    .BindTo(Model.Publications)
    .Filter(FilterType.Contains)
    .TemplateId("pubListItemTemplate")
    .HeaderTemplateId("pubListHeaderTemplate")
)

<script>
    function onPubFilter(ev) {

        var filterValue = ev.filter.value;
        ev.preventDefault();

        this.dataSource.filter({
            filters: [
                {
                    field: "Combined",
                    operator: "contains",
                    value: filterValue
                }
            ]
        });

    }
</script>
```